# Masonry + Wordpress Theme = Div Overlap

Tags: wordpress, themes, jquery-masonry

I have accounted for the images, yet I still get a DIV overlap on a handful of the DIVS when using Masonry. Some of the other DIVS have varying top/bottom MARGINs.

Can you take a look and tell me what I have done wrong?

http://hn.deadradioentertainment.com/

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the case that your images are not loaded when the masonry starts laying out the divs. And, once the images are loaded the layout does not update.

You need to either:

1. update/call the masonry once all images are loaded or
2. in your style.css try setting the height of the thumbnail images.

   .post-entry-thumbnail img {
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     height: 155px;
   }